# Некорректный transform position при создании объекта

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Возможно вопрос банален, и сам чувствую что где то я затупил на легчайшем.

И так. У меня есть save.file в котором лежат вектора позиций объектов которое нужно создать на карте. Вектора которые записываются в файл и берутся от туда правильные. До файла никаких претензий. Всё с файлом норм.

```
GameObject tmp;
foreach (var r in data.ResourcesInMap)
{
    Debug.Log($"Name resource - {(TypeResource)r.idResourceType} | Vector before - {r.vect.x}.{r.vect.y}.{r.vect.z}");

    tmp = Instantiate(resources[(TypeResource)r.idResourceType], map.transform, true);

    tmp.transform.position = new Vector3(r.vect.x, r.vect.y, r.vect.z);

    Debug.Log($"Name resource - {(TypeResource)r.idResourceType} | Vector after all changes - {tmp.transform.position}");

}
```

Таким образом я создаю объекты. Сначала беру parent transform для того что бы объекты были вложены в родительский. А потом я меняю позицию для правильного отображения. Вот что выходит в логе.

> Name resource - Grass | Vector before - 0,24.-0,24.0

> Name resource - Grass | Vector after all changes - (0,2, -0,2, 0,0)

Мало того что я не понимаю почему идёт округление с 0,24 до 0,2. Так ещё координаты созданного объекта другие.

> Выходит позиция (2.64, -0.24, 0)

Карта ресурсов построилась практически нормально. Просто все объекты созданы на правой половине родительского элемента. Они смещены вправо, но Instantiate показывал правильные координаты. Ось х почему то меняется. ХЗ, поможет ли эта инфа вам но, везде использую компонент Rect Transform. Pivot родительского элемента находится на вверху.

Помогите, уверен в том что не учёл что то. Не могу понять где меняется значение с 0,24 на 2,64.

Comment: `не понимаю почему идёт округление с 0,24 до 0,2` - Когда вы выводите Vector3 в консоль идет округление до 1 знака.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Как и думал. Дополнил одну строчку.

> tmp.transform.position = new Vector3(tmp.transform.position.x + r.vect.x, tmp.transform.position.y + r.vect.y, r.vect.z);